# Can I do a loop/function for this in R? (and how would I do it?)

Tags: r, function, loops, csv

I'm currently using R to backtest some Football/Soccer Odds, using a model to create my own odds.

At the moment it's quite a very long process and I'm curious as if there is a loop/function that I can make to help speed up the process.

This piece of code collects the results over the full season.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
options(max.print = 9999)
Res <- read_html("https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/?month=all")
tbls_ls <- Res %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

Results <- as.data.frame(tbls_ls)
Results <- Results[,c(1:2)]
names(Results) <- c("Fixture","Score")
Results <- tidyr::separate(Results, Fixture, into =c("HomeTeam","AwayTeam"), sep = " - ")
Results <- tidyr::separate(Results, Score, into = c("FTHG","FTAG"), sep = ":")
Results <- Results %>% tidyr::drop_na()
Results <- Results[,c(1:4)]
write.csv(Results, file = "Results.csv")
rownames(Results) <- 1:nrow(Results)
```

I'm backtesting odds by game week and for the League I'm testing there are 10 games per game week. This code removes the previous game week and sets up that weeks fixtures as if they were yet to be played. This removes gameweek 29(the last in the this league)

```
ResultsEdit <- Results #[-(1:10),]
FixEdit <- ResultsEdit[,c(1:2)]

ResultsEditE <- Results [-(1:10),]
ResultsEditE %>% tidyr::drop_na()
write.csv(Results, file="ResultsEditE")
```

If I wanted to remove gameweek 29 & 28 and use gameweek 28 as fixtures yet to be played I'd edit to the code to

```
ResultsEdit <- Results [-(1:10),]
ResultsEditE <- Results [-(1:20),]
```

So on and so forth the futher I go back.

This is the Poisson code for predicting Odds

```
library("vcd")

source("http://www.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~voss/projects/2010-sports/Football.R")
results0 <- read.csv("ResultsEditE",stringsAsFactors = F) 
results0$X <- NULL
countres <- results0$FTHG + results0$FTAG
tg <- countres
fretabtg<-table(tg)
gf <- goodfit(fretabtg, type="poisson", method="ML")
Table0 <- Table(results0)
games <- results0
g <- nrow(games)
Y <- matrix(0,2*g,1)
for (i in 1:g) {
  Y[((2*i)-1)] <- games[i,3]
  Y[(2*i)] <- games[i,4]
}

teams <- sort(unique(c(games[,1], games[,2])), decreasing = FALSE) 
n <- length(teams) 
X <- matrix(0,2*g,((2*n)+1))
for (i in 1:g) { 
  M <- which(teams == games[i,1]) 
  N <- which(teams == games[i,2]) 
  X[((2*i)-1),M] <- 1 
  X[((2*i)-1),N+n] <- -1 
  X[(2*i),N] <- 1 
  X[(2*i),M+n] <- -1 
  X[((2*i)-1),((2*n)+1)] <- 1 
}

x <- qr(X)
x$rank
XX <- X[,-1]



TeamParameters <- Parameters(results0)
SimSeason <- Games(TeamParameters)
SimSeason <- SimSeason %>% tidyr::drop_na()

SimTable <- Table(SimSeason)
Simulations <- Sim(TeamParameters,3)

Probabilities <- ProbTable(TeamParameters,"", "")
ResultProbabilities<- ResultProbs(Probabilities)

cat("\nHome Win True Odds:", 100/ResultProbabilities$HomeWin)
cat("\nDraw True Odds:", 100/ResultProbabilities$Draw)
cat("\nAway Win True Odds:", 100/ResultProbabilities$AwayWin)
```

And this code gives me the odds for the game week that I want.

```
run_probs <- function(h_team, a_team) {
  Probabilities <- ProbTable(TeamParameters, h_team, a_team)
  ResultProbabilities <- ResultProbs(Probabilities)

  cat(paste("\n", h_team, "VS", a_team))
  cat("\nHome Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$HomeWin)
  cat("\nDraw:", 100/ResultProbabilities$Draw)
  cat("\nAway Win:", 100/ResultProbabilities$AwayWin)  

  return(ResultProbabilities)
}

FixEdit <- head(FixEdit, n=10)

prob_list <- Map(run_probs, FixEdit$HomeTeam,FixEdit$AwayTeam)
```

What I'm desperate to do is reduce the amount of time it takes me to run through a season. 
Using the code I've provided as an example is it possible to do some sort of loop for this?

```
Run the game week 29 removal code, run the poisson code, run the code for giving me the odds for the game week - save the results in a CSV
Run the game week 28 removal code, run the poisson code, run the code for giving me the odds for the game week - save the results in a CSV
```

etc etc.

Hopefully returning something like this for each game week.

```
             Home            Away   Home Win      Draw  Away Win
1       Leicester     Aston Villa   1.209044  9.009009  16.18123
2         Chelsea         Everton   1.634788   5.09165  5.216484
3  Manchester Utd Manchester City      3.125  4.199916  2.265006
4         Arsenal        West Ham   1.786352   4.52284   4.56621
5         Burnley       Tottenham    3.08642  3.904725  2.379819
6  Crystal Palace         Watford   2.309469  3.079766  4.128819
7       Liverpool     Bournemouth   1.160362  10.04016  25.97403
8   Sheffield Utd         Norwich   1.637465  3.868472  7.639419
9     Southampton       Newcastle   2.198769  3.687316  3.654971
10         Wolves        Brighton   1.785714  4.016064  5.230126
```

Sorry for the long post and sorry if I've made no sense. Feel free to lock/remove post if it just seems like gibberish.

Comment: ScoutingForJay, please take a moment and try to respect the "M" in [mcve]. There is a lot of code in here that does absolutely nothing (for us), has no lasting effect (side-effect or introspection only), and just clouds up your question. Examples of this: unsaved calls to `glm`, `mean`, `var`, `table`, and any line of code used for **you** to look at something, but since it is not shown here I can only infer that we don't need to see that line of code. Long questions can be a deterrent, consider shortening to a least amount of *reproducible* code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I've just skimmed your code, but since you're already using `tidyverse`, you could definitely make it shorter and more readable by starting to use the pipe (`%>%`) operator: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a lot of code that is not used in what you are trying to accomplish.
You also seem to have a problem with a few games that are not in the correct order, which may be problematic.

Below is my take on running this a bit more efficiently - if I understood correctly what you were going for:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
options(max.print = 9999)
Res <- read_html("https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/?month=all")
tbls_ls <- Res %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
Results <- setnames(as.data.table(tbls_ls)[, 1:2], c("Fixture","Score"))
Results[, Round:=NA_integer_]
Results[grep("Round", Results$Fixture)]$Round <- as.numeric(gsub("\\..*", "", grep("Round", Results$Fixture, value = TRUE)))
setnafill(Results, type="locf", cols="Round")
Results[, c("HomeTeam", "AwayTeam") := tstrsplit(Fixture, " - ", 2)]
Results[, c("FTHG","FTAG") := tstrsplit(Score, ":", 2)]
Results <- Results[, `:=`(Fixture=NULL, Score=NULL)][!is.na(FTAG)]
Results[, c("FTHG", "FTAG"):=lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=c("FTHG", "FTAG")]
setorder(Results, -Round)
setcolorder(Results, c(2:5,1))
library("vcd")
source("http://www.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~voss/projects/2010-sports/Football.R")
resultsList0 <- lapply(rev(sapply(2:30, function(x) head(seq_len(x), -1))), function(x) Results[Round %in% x])

getProbs <- function(y){
  FixEdit <- as.data.frame(y[Round==max(Round), c(1:2)])
  TeamParameters <- Parameters(setDF(y[,1:4]))
  run_probs <- function(h_team, a_team) {
    Probabilities <- ProbTable(TeamParameters, h_team, a_team)
    return(ResultProbs(Probabilities))
  }
  res <- Map(run_probs, FixEdit$HomeTeam, FixEdit$AwayTeam)
  data.table(FixEdit, 100/rbindlist(res))
}

out <- setNames(lapply(resultsList0, getProbs), paste0("Up_to_Wk_", rev(2:30)))
# to export to csv:
# lapply(seq_along(out), function(x) fwrite(out[[x]], file=paste0(names(out)[x], ".csv")))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi, this is fantastic work - thank you very much. It's very nearly exactly what I'm looking for. I think there may be an issue with the odds though. Going back to how I've been manually doing it. My odds for Liverpool vs Manchester united (in up to week 24), I had home: 1.58 draw: 4.55 away: 6.75. When I ran the code you provided it gave me Home: 1.39 Draw: 5.57 Away: 10.17 .... What do you think would be the reason for the discrepency?

Comment: Looking at the raw table, you may have to consider how you want to treat data belonging to different rounds, or missing data (2 games less than 10 per round for that time span). I kept rounds together and successively removed those, and there was one postponed game West Ham - Liverpool in the 18th round listed after the 24th. If you wish to keep that order, perhaps sort them by date or manually assign weeks.